# method_missingでsleepメソッドを呼んだ時にフリーズする理由

Tags: ruby

こんにちは。
自分で一生懸命調べれば解決できるかも知れませんが、
ここで質問した方が役に立つお話が聞けるかも知れないと思って質問します。

Rubyで下のようなコードを実行すると

```rb
class A
  def method_missing(method, *args)
    puts "ZZZ" if method == :sleep
  end
end

a = A.new
a.sleep
a.send(:sleep)
```

`a.sleep` は期待通り "ZZZ" を出力するのですが、次の行の
`a.send(:sleep)` はフリーズします。

どうしてこうなるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`send(:sleep)`だと、privateメソッドの `Kernel.#sleep`を呼べるためです。
https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Kernel/m/sleep.html

Aクラスのインスタンスには`sleep`メソッドはprivateメソッドとして存在します。
これは、Kernelモジュールに定義されたメソッドはprivateメソッドとしてAクラスにも定義されるためです。

これは例えば`method`メソッドを使うと確かめられます。

```rb
class A
  def method_missing(method, *args)
    puts "ZZZ" if method == :sleep
  end
end

a = A.new

p a.method(:sleep)
# => #<Method: A(Kernel)#sleep(*)>

p a.public_method(:sleep)
# => -:10:in `public_method': method `sleep' for class `A' is  private (NameError)
#   from -:10:in `<main>'
```

そして、`a.sleep`の形式でのメソッド呼び出しはpublicメソッドしか呼び出せないため、privateメソッドである`Kernel.#sleep`を呼び出せず`method_missing`に処理が移ります。

対して`a.send(:sleep)`はprivateメソッドでも呼び出せるので、method_missingが呼ばれずに`Kernel.#sleep`が呼ばれます。

`send`を`public_send`に変えると`method_missing`を通るようになって、`public_send`でも"ZZZ"が表示されるようになると思います。

Answer (score 2):

直接的な原因は`send(:sleep)`で`Kernel#sleep`が呼ばれてしまっていることにあるようです。その証拠に、`sleep`を`hoge`に置換すると思った通りに動作します。

```rb
class A
  def method_missing(method, *args)
    puts "ZZZ" if method.to_sym == :hoge
  end
end

a = A.new
a.hoge
a.send(:hoge)
# ZZZ
# ZZZ
```

色々試したのですが、どうやら「`send`で`Kernel`モジュールにあるメソッドと同名のメソッドを呼び出そうとすると、`method_missing`で補足されずに`Kernel`モジュール内のメソッドが呼ばれてしまうようです（`warn`メソッドで確認しました）。
この挙動がRubyのバグなのかどうかはこれから確認してみますね。

---

私の確認不足で、単に`send`はプライベートメソッドを呼び出せる、`Kernel#sleep`や`Kernel#warn`はプライベートメソッドである、ということのようです。